# mysql problem with mysqldump/mysqlcheck table

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I have problem with mysql backup via mysqldump.exe

I tried to do mysql backup via cmd commands:

```
mysqldump.exe -u root -p -P 3306 --add-drop-table --all-databases --force >F:\backup\backup20230417.dmp
```

After about 1h there is an error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'UNLOCK TABLES': MySQL server has gone away (2006)
Db_1
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) when trying to connect
DB2
```

i tried to manipulate innodb_buffer_pool_size but it didnt help.

Then i wanted to do mysqlcheck of my databases, but results was the same.
It hung up on one of the table for an hour, and then crushed.

About 6 mounths ago i did the same operation and everything went well.
I'm using MySql 5.7 on Windows Server 2012R2

How can i make my backup in this situation?